# How do I perform a clean install with an SSD cache

Tags: windows, laptop, installation, ssd, cache

I recently purchased a Sony Vaio T series Ultrabook that has a 24GB SSD cache that uses the ExpressCache software from DiskKeeper. It looks like this is an OEM only solution and I don't see any software downloads for it. How can I do a clean install on this machine without losing the ssd cache? I have a Windows 8 Professional license I'd like to use for this machine.

Comment: Are you sure that it is using Express Cache and not something like the Z77 chipset with Intel RST?

Comment: Worst case, pull the platter out, put in an old one and see if you can enable caching. Make sure that your BIOS is set to RAID instead of ACHI

Comment: Express Cache was installed when I got it. The exact model is [SVT15112CXS](http://www.docs.sony.com/release/SPECS/SVT15112CXS_mksp.pdf).

Comment: Just wondering, why is it important to keep the cache? Do you mean to ask about the drivers and how to properly set it up after installing a new OS?